# How do I fix this Tuist installation error: curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404?

Tags: terminal, tuist

I am trying to install Tuist but I get the error below in Terminal. Could anyone explain how to fix that.

**Downloading tuistenv...
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404**

Trying to install Tuist

Answer (score 1):

You need to check your git version with command
git --version. I had the same problem with "unknown option `sort=v:refname'" and git version was 2.15.0.
After I updated and linked to git version 2.43.0 problem solved.

If it is not fix your problem, do not focus last line "Downloading tuistenv... curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404".
Check for upper lines for more info like "unknown option `sort=v:refname'"

Answer (score 0):

You must to update your git to last version to do this: `brew install git` then try installing Tuist again.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using the old git version 2.15.0 (You can see it by `git --version`) and I updated my git to the latest version by home-brew (`brew install git`), but after the installation when I used `git --version`, It still was showing the old version 2.15.0. So I just uninstall the git version 2.15.0, by the following steps:

First check the path of your git by using:

```
which git
```

It will give you the path like this:

```
/usr/local/git/
```

Now use the below command line to uninstall it:

```
/usr/local/git/uninstall.sh
```

After that check your git version:

```
git --version
```

Mine was `git version 2.39.2 (Apple Git-143)`

Now try to install twist using the following command:

```
curl -Ls https://install.tuist.io | bash
```

Now it will install the twist with out any error. After installing, check the twist version to ensure if it is installed in your machine:

```
tuist version
```